# Search integers with Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I managed to get Sunspot working in my rails setup. My rails setup renders graphs (Chartwell) with input from my database (integers), example: "design: 80, art: 20, code: 40".

Is there a way that I can search for "design" and get all elements with design > 70 (integer, for instance) as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving code, so I'll improvise.

Since you have everything working, I assume you already have defined your `design` field indexed in `searchable` definition in your model.

After you've done that, you will have a `.search` block for Sunspot (or Model) in your active code (most probably in a controller).

So, let's suppose your model name is Graph.

```
design = params[:design] # guessing, again.
Graph.search do
    with(:design).greater_than(design)
    # .... other conditions
end
```

This should work for you.

***UPDATE***:
Assuming that you have a `design:integer` column in your db

In your event.rb:

```
searchable do
    text :name, :location, :date_search
    integer :design
end
```

in your events_controller.rb:

```
@search = Event.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:design).greater_than(params[:design].to_i)
end
```

Note: You should pass `:design` as a parameter with your search form

Comment: Thanks, here's some code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJGto. It's probably a little different. Sorry for not providing it in the first place.

Comment: If I add this code I don't see anything on my homepage. Here's the full events_controller code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xFnAv